# Help with my post?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Sports Stack Exchange post: **Is there any formula or method to determine the number of player to play that sport(Cricket, Football)?** which being broad I edited to this one. [Is there any method that determined the number of player in a Football game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16285/is-there-any-method-that-determined-the-number-of-player-in-a-football-game)

My previous wording make it broad and not answerable, So I edited that question and tried to make it more answerable. Which is on hold now, if that question is answerable will that hold be removed? I will gladly accept any action of community and be careful on next one.

**Previous question before editing**:
    This question got downvoted because it is too broad and through comment on 
    it, I now know there are no formula, no of player were determined because 
    some one wrote that in a rule book.
 So, **is there any way to 
    prevent further downvoting** on this question. I just joined a week 
    ago. 
    Next time i will be careful before asking a question.

Comment: In the end the goal isn't to fabricate a good question to get experience. I found myself doing that when I first came across SE too. But if the goal here is knowledge rather than having attention (it is!), then try not to worry too much about voting. Not saying you did or didn't have that question long in mind, I just know that I tried to "find" my own questions early on rather than waiting for natural ones to come up. I've found some good questions I ask get no love, and many questions I think weren't my best get votes. So be it! Focus on giving good answerable questions and you'll be fine.

Comment: @JeopardTempest thanks

Comment: Indeed reputation does have a few purposes, at least at low levels... but you can also get it quite well by editing questions and answers (often there are little grammatical things that need fixing, links that should be added, etc). Or you can try to find long unanswered questions that you are well-versed in, and try to give good quality thorough (usually referenced) answers. Be patient, Sports SE seems tough to get into, as many questions have single rulebook answers or specialized topics... but over time, you'll find your place if your goal is doing good stuff :-)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest the question being on hold I tried to edit that question as well as this meta question. Is this a good thing or not?

Comment: Pretty reasonable edit to me!